# Can non-linear objects be defined using linear ones?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, tensors, nonlinear-system

Tensors are said to be multi-linear maps. My question is if tensors can be used to describe non-linear systems? Or if non-linear mappings can be made using tensors?

Answer (score 1):

They certainly can, some famous nonlinear systems that are nonlinear and are described using tensors are General Relativity, where the equations involve the Riemann curvature tensor, and also non-abelian Yang-Mills theory, where you have the field strength tensor. In these theories, the field acts as its own source, so it's in general not true that a linear combination of solutions will be a solution itself.

Think of the case of the one-dimensional derivative. It is a linear map between functions, and can be thought as an operator on a vector space. But that does not mean everything you write with derivatives will be a linear differential equation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not that advanced in math, therefore didn't get most of the things you described. But then are there nonlinear systems which can not be defined using linear ones?

Comment: It's very difficult to give an answer without understanding precisely what you mean by "defined". The whole point of linear systems being interesting is that you can write the general solution as a combination of simpler ones.
For nonlinear systems, that's not possible, even if the formulas for their dynamics involve a linear map at some point. I'm not sure if avoiding any linear maps even in their equations of motion would make substantial difference, because they already violate what you are looking for in linear systems, anyway.